# Android Adding Text inside switch toggle. Newer API approach

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add text inside switches and expect toggle to completely cover the texts

I was able to achieve this in API 16 with below option

```
<Switch
android:textOff="off"
android:showText="true"
android:textOn="on"/>
```

However same switch looks odd in the higher version(i'm testing with API 27) where switch toggle is a round icon behind the text.

Is there a way i can fit the text inside the switch toggle using **native library/methods.**

Comment: I doubt it. The Material Design `Switch` is not designed to have text.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code in GitHub. After some addition and modification, I get what I need. This toggle button has YES NO text on it and works like switch button. You can give it a go.

```
public class ToggleButton extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

FrameLayout layout;
TextView toggleCircle;
View background_oval_off, background_oval_on;
int dimen;

private Boolean _crossfadeRunning = false;
private ObjectAnimator _oaLeft, _oaRight;

public ToggleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.toggle_button, this, true);


    background_oval_off = findViewById(R.id.background_oval_off);
    background_oval_on = findViewById(R.id.background_oval_on);
    toggleCircle = findViewById(R.id.toggleCircle);
    layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);


    layout.setOnClickListener(this);

    //get a pixel size for a particular dimension - will differ by device according to screen density
    dimen = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toggle_width);
    _oaLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toggleCircle, "x", dimen / 2, 0).setDuration(250);
    _oaRight = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(toggleCircle, "x", 0, dimen / 2).setDuration(250);

    //setState();
}

public ToggleButton(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public void setState(String answer) {

    Log.d("simul", "ans - " + answer);

    if (answer.equals("1")) {
        toggleCircle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green));
        toggleCircle.setX(dimen / 2);
        _crossfadeViews(background_oval_off, background_oval_on, 1);
        toggleCircle.setText("Yes");
    } else {
        toggleCircle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red));
        toggleCircle.setX(0);
        _crossfadeViews(background_oval_on, background_oval_off, 1);
        toggleCircle.setText("No");
    }
}

private void _crossfadeViews(final View begin, View end, int duration) {
    _crossfadeRunning = true;

    end.setAlpha(0f);
    end.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    end.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(duration).setListener(null);
    begin.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(duration).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            begin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _crossfadeRunning = false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (_oaLeft.isRunning() || _oaRight.isRunning() || _crossfadeRunning) return;

    if (toggleCircle.getText().equals("Yes")) {
        _oaLeft.start();
        _crossfadeViews(background_oval_on, background_oval_off, 110);
        toggleCircle.setText("No");
        toggleCircle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red));
        mListener.toggleButtonClickListener("No");
    } else {
        _oaRight.start();
        _crossfadeViews(background_oval_off, background_oval_on, 400);
        toggleCircle.setText("Yes");
        toggleCircle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green));
        mListener.toggleButtonClickListener("Yes");

    }
}

public ToggleButtonListener mListener = null;

public void setToggleButtonClickListener(ToggleButtonListener listener) {

    mListener = listener;
}

public interface ToggleButtonListener {
    public void toggleButtonClickListener(String content);
}
}
```

toogle_button_red_oval.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
            android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="@dimen/toggle_circle_radius" android:right="@dimen/toggle_circle_radius">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
            android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
            android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

toogle_button_green_oval.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
            android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="@dimen/toggle_circle_radius" android:right="@dimen/toggle_circle_radius">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
            android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
            android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

toogle_button_circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<size
    android:height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
    android:width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter" />
</shape>
```

toogle_button.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/toggle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toggle_height"
        android:id="@+id/background_oval_off"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_black_oval" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/toggle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toggle_height"
        android:id="@+id/background_oval_on"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_green_oval"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toggle_circle_diameter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/toggleCircle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toggle_text_size"
        android:text="No"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_button_circle"/>
</FrameLayout>

</merge>
```

XML layout code

```
<package.name.ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</cpackage.name.ToggleButton>
```

Java Code :

```
ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
toggleButton.setToggleButtonClickListener(new ToggleButton.ToggleButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void toggleButtonClickListener(String content) {
                if (content.equals("Yes")) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```

dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="toggle_width">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="toggle_height">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="toggle_circle_diameter">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="toggle_circle_radius">25dp</dimen>
```

Sorry for this long long answer. I had to add all the code here. please let me know if anything missing here. :)